# How to use the timeout command in batch language?

Tags: windows, batch-file, testing

I actually wanted to create a timer using batch program and when I run the code the output is not the way I want. The screen continues flicking without decreasing the second. Can someone Help me. Thanks alot.

```
@echo off
set countdown=10
:loop
if %countdown% == 0 goto end
cls
echo %countdown% 
timeout /t 1 /NOBREAK
set/a count=%countdown%-1
goto loop
:end
cls
echo Time's up!
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this line `set/a count=%countdown%-1` by this one `set /a countdown=countdown-1` or by a shortened `set /a countdown-=1`.

```
@echo off
set "countdown=10"
:loop
if "%countdown%" EQU "0" goto end
cls
echo %countdown% 
set /a countdown-=1
timeout /t 1 /NOBREAK>nul
goto loop
:end
cls
echo Time's up!
pause
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working. And why it has this sign " on   set/a "countdown=10"

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it without the goto / label

```
@echo off
Set count=10
Setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
For /L %%a in (1,1,!count!) DO (
    Set /a count=!count! - 1
    (ECHO <esc>[1;1H<esc>[K!count!)
    (
        TIMEOUT 1 >nul
    )
)

ECHO times up!    
pause
```

`<esc>[1;1H<esc>[K` Sets the position of the text (line;column) and clears the line from that point. `<esc>` represents the ANSI escape character.
Using the ANSI cursor positioning allows you to refresh text on screen selectively, without having to clear the whole screen.

Comment: Just to mention, that you may need the latest version of Windows 10, for console Virtual Terminal sequences.

Comment: Ansi Sequences are Supported by all versions of Windows 10 
- amendment - after reviewing, The Cursor Positioning System is indeed NOT ansi.

Comment: To clarify, my point is that the OP did not specify their OS version, simply Windows, therefore I felt it worth mentioning that cmd.exe by default will be unable to do this, unless the OP is using the latest OS.